# Guice: Assisted injections and providers

Tags: java, guice, assisted-inject

Suppose I have a class as follows:

```
public class ComplicatedImpl implements Complicated {
    @Inject
    public ComplicatedImpl(Integer normal, @Assisted String assisted);

    public void addListener(Listener listener);
}
```

Now, I have a `ComplicatedFactory` like so:

```
public interface ComplicatedFactory {
    public Complicated build(String assisted);
}
```

Is it possible to, when using `FactoryModuleBuilder`, bind a `ComplicatedFactory` such that, when `build()` is invoked, we do the equivalent of

```
ComplicatedImpl impl = new ComplicatedImpl(normal, assisted);
impl.addListener(listener);
return impl;
```

as opposed to the normal case of returning a new `ComplicatedImpl` directly?

I had throughout of trying to bind `ComplicatedImpl` to some form of `Provider`, but it seems that I'd be going around in circles with that...

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible in Guice; [FactoryModuleBuilder](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) can do very little other than mixing explicit constructor arguments with dependencies. Luckily, writing a manual factory is relatively easy:

```
public class ListeningComplicatedFactory {
  @Inject Provider<Integer> normalProvider;

  public Complicated createComplicated(String assisted, Listener listener) {
    ComplicatedImpl impl = new ComplicatedImpl(normalProvider.get(), assisted);

    // If ComplicatedImpl uses member injection, inject an Injector and call
    // injector.injectMembers(impl) to call @Inject-annotated methods/fields.

    impl.addListener(listener);
    return impl;
  }
}
```

If you are willing to put `addListener` on the `Complicated` interface, you also have the option of writing a wrapper that injects a ComplicatedFactory, creates new instances, and calls `addListener` on them immediately. This can be especially effective if you bind ComplicatedFactory in a [PrivateModule](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) and then only expose your new ComplicatedWrapperFactory, making your ComplicatedWrapperFactory the only way to create new Complicated implementations.